# Markov Chain Snakes and Ladders

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am really stuck on the following question:

[image]

So first I need to work out the transition matrix. But I am not sure how? Lets say I am at square 0 and I want to square 1, is the probability of moving to that square .5 since the coin is fair. I tried to work out the matrix:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The numbers in red are just to help with the indexes. Is this matrix correct?

I am stuck on how work out that that I will finish in 4 turns given that I am on square 3?
I was thinking of using the nth probability state vector, let n be the turn number, so I would need to find $\pi^{\{4\}}$ but wont this be very tedious since our matrix is 10x10... And I don't know how to condition on the fact we are on square 3.

Edit:
I was looking over my book again and re-read n-stage transition probabilities. So I guess I need to use this
$$ P^{(n)}_{ij} = P(X_n = j | X_0 = i)$$

So I need to work out
$$ P^{(4)}_{39} = P(X_4 = 9 | X_0 = 3)$$
$$= \sum_{i=3}^{9} p_{3i}p_{i9}$$
but working this summation out gives 0. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you consider moving from 4 to 7 or 8 to 2 as a step? I would think that the number of steps should be equal to the number of tosses.

Comment: @deb Isn't moving 4 to 7 just 1 step? You automatically go there anyway. I am not sure what you mean by number of steps equals number of tosses?

Comment: If you say so, the matrix P is correct except (8,2) should be 1 not (8,1)

Comment: Let $p_s(t)$ be the prob you reach 9 in at most t steps from s. Then $p_3(4) = 0.5 p_4(3) + 0.5 p_5(3) = ...$

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good reference for exactly your problem: http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/markov/markov.html

Since landing on 4 or 8 moves the player immediately (i.e. without requiring another turn, Your transition matrix $P$ should actually be the black numbers below:
$$
\begin{matrix}
&
\color{red}0&
\color{red}1&
\color{red}2&
\color{red}3&
\color{red}5&
\color{red}6&
\color{red}7&
\color{red}9\\
\color{red}0&0 & .5 & .5 & 0 & 0 &0&0&0\\
\color{red}1&0&0&.5&.5&0&0&0&0 \\
\color{red}2&0&0&0&.5&0&0&.5&0\\
\color{red}3&0&0&0&0&.5&0&.5&0\\
\color{red}5&0&0&0&0&0&.5&.5&0\\
\color{red}6&0&0&.5&0&0&0&.5&0\\
\color{red}7&0&0&.5&0&0&0&0&.5\\
\color{red}9&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{matrix}
$$

Spaces 4 and 8 are removed since it's impossible to move to and stay on them in the same turn. Then the initial state of the player on space 3 is defined as $X$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The formula $XP^n$ yields the probabilities of the player being at each state after $n$ moves. In your case, starting at space 3 and tossing the coin 4 times:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&{1\over 8}&{1\over 8}&
{1 \over 16}& 0&{3 \over 16}&
{1 \over 2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The probability of you reaching space 9 within 4 turns is ${1 \over 2}$.