# 'Snakes and Ladders' As a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains

I was having this discussion with a friend the other day.

Imagine a game of "Snakes and Ladders" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_ladders) - but now there a two dice in this game : One of the die has 6 sides and the other die has 10 sides. In this new version of the game, both players start rolling the 6 sided die - they continue to roll this die until they climb a snake or a ladder. If it was a snake, they keep rolling the 6 sided die until further notice  - if it was a ladder, they switch to the 10 sided die until further notice. The goal of the game is still to reach the last square on the board.

If this was the original game of Snakes and Ladders with only one die, I have seen many examples online that show you how to model this game using a Markov Chain and how to create the transition matrix (e.g. [Markov Chain Snakes and Ladders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695191/markov-chain-snakes-and-ladders))

But in this game where there are two dice, I am not sure how to create the Markov Chain and transition matrix. In this new version of the game, I would be interested in knowing if the Absorption Theorem of Markov Chains can still be used to estimate the number of turns required to win from a specific square on the board.

Is this even possible to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Make two separate MCs: one with 6-sided die and another with 10-sided die. Now add the inter transitions as applicable. This will be lengthy, but still quite easy to do.

Comment: Just include a specification of which die the player is currently using as a part of the state.

Comment: Perhaps this is a "hidden variable Markov" process.  The hidden variable having two values,  "before ladder" and "after ladder".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model

Answer (score 4):

Sounds fun! Definitely possible.

Here's one way you could set it up.

Think about having 2 separate boards. One you roll a d6 (6-sided die) and the other you roll a d10 (10-sided die). Then all you need to fill in are the transitions from one board to another.

The finishing tile is a little tricky. Either you can think about sending both boards to the same tile or be prepared to deal with a sum in your answer:
(d6 start -> d6 finish) + (d6 start -> d10 finish). These would be disjoint events so the expected values just add.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out!

Comment: do you think you can expand on your answer if you have time (e.g. show a sample markov chain)?

Comment: @antonoyaro8 My main hesitance is dealing with how many setup choices there are. For example, how do you deal with landing on spaces with a snake or ladder? You immediately get transferred to another space without a move. So these tiles are merely placeholders and could be omitted.  Also there's a matter of scale, the number of positions you'd need for your game would be around 200. So around a 200x200 adjacency matrix? Since you want to make one version use a d10,  having a board of length 10 seems like a minimum requirement. Even that would have a 20x20 adjacency matrix.

Comment: I'd encourage you to try implementing yourself. Even without the switching between 2 different dice, this problem is large enough you probably want to program in the values of your transition matrix rather than writing them by hand. I'd start by implementing the vanilla game.